# reading my facebook group posts via API, while on development mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I'd like to read group feed of a group I admin, while yet to apply for app review.
I admin private and public groups on my accounts for testing purposes, admin the app, and created a test app.
I gave the following permissions: 'groups_show_list', 'groups_access_member_info', 'publish_to_groups'

The problems I encounter:

1. I get an empty list of groups from the api: `https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/groups`
2. When trying to read group feed of my public group, using the api: `https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed` , passing token and limit, I get the following error:

> {'error': {'message': '(#3) Missing Permission', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 3, 'fbtrace_id': 'A3CWyW2GZbZTn8auSEgbWLS'}}

Is it possible to solve those issues before applying to review?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access any type of facebook group private or public, whether you're admin or not, because recently facebook due to some privacy reasons, has removed permissions related to groups such as publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info' from their graph Api's latest version which is 19.0 and was released in Jan 2023. Applications created before that are and can still use these permissions as those apps are built on older graph api versions, however facebook has given a deadline of april 2024 and after that they will be removing all permissions related to groups and specifically groups api from all versions of graph api.
you can visit this link for reference.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version19.0.
Hope you got your answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).